# calculating sla based on minutes on working hours and business days

Tags: php

I am trying to build a function which calculates ticket sla based on working hours and skip calculations for non working hours and weekends and it shifts time accordingly to next day or to next working day. My response sla to a ticket is 30 minutes and if ticket insert date is within weekdays {Mon-Fri} and within business hours {08:00:00 - 17:00:00}, then my end date should be calculated based on following factors:

1. for Monday to Thursday, time should shift to next 30 minutes in working hours in case insertDate falls within working hours, e.g. if
   case1: insertDate = '2020-07-16 16:00:00'; here, I am getting expected result, endDate ='2020-07-16 16:30:00';
   and  if insertDate timestamp exceeds the working hours window e.g. if
   case2: insertDate = '2020-07-16 16:50:00'; here, I am not getting expected result, which should be endDate ='2020-07-17 08:20:00';
2. for Weekends(Sat to Sun), any ticket created in this weekend window, the calculations should start from Mon and from 08:00:00 hours
   case3: insertDate = '2020-07-18 16:50:00'; here, I am not getting expected result, which should be endDate ='2020-07-20 08:30:00';

Below is my code, which works for case1 fine, ubt breaks for case2 and case3, any help on this is highly appreciated.

```
<?php
function calculateSLA($totalMinutes){
$insertDate = '2020-07-16 16:00:00';
$endDate = date('Y-m-d H:00:00',strtotime($insertDate)); 
//$t_min = date('i',strtotime($insertDate));
$BusinessStart = '08:00:00';
$BusinessEnd   = '17:00:00';
$i           = 1;
$flag        = false;

while ($totalMinutes > 0) {
    $day = date('D', strtotime($endDate)); // fetching day of week
    if ($day == 'Sat') { // checking if saturday thenskip by adding 2 day to end date
        $endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($endDate . " +2 Day")) . ' ' . $BusinessStart; // adding 2 day if saturday
        continue;
    }
    $diff  = strtotime($BusinessEnd) - strtotime(date("H:i:s", strtotime($insertDate))); // getting difference of time of office end date and result end date
    var_dump($diff);
    $mins = $diff / (60); // difference in mins.
    if ($mins > $totalMinutes) {
        $mins = $totalMinutes;
        $flag  = true; 
    } else {
        $mins = $totalMinutes - $mins; // substracting mins from total minutes left
        
    }
    $endDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+$mins Minute", strtotime($insertDate))); // adding subtracted minutes
    if (!$flag) {
        $endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($insertDate . " +1 Day")) . ' ' . $BusinessStart; // if not last loop add day to result end date
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
echo $endDate;
}
calculateSLA(30);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will post my version of the function. You pass the DateTime of ticket submission and get the DateTime of the allowed response.

```
function calculateSLA(DateTime $reportDate): DateTime {
  $responseDate = (clone $reportDate);

  // check conditions and add 1 minute to provided date 30 times (so 30 minutes)
  for($i=0; $i<30;$i++) {
    // if time is before 8:00 (working hours) skip to 8:00
    if ($responseDate->format('G') < 8) {
      $responseDate->setTime(8, 0);
    }

    // if time is after 17:00 (working hours) skip to next day at 8:00
    if ($responseDate->format('G') >= 17) {
      $responseDate->add(new DateInterval('PT15H'));
      $responseDate->setTime(8, 0);
    }

    // if at any time it is weekend skip to monday at 8:00
    if (in_array($responseDate->format('D'), ['Sat', 'Sun'])) {
      $responseDate = $responseDate->modify('next monday 8:00');
    }

    $responseDate->add(new DateInterval('PT1M'));
  }

  return $responseDate;
}
```

And the code i used to test this function with different conditions:

```
function test(string $date, string $expected) {
  $result = calculateSLA(new DateTime($date));
  echo 'date: '.$date.', expected: '.$expected.', got: '.$result->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').' '.($result->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') === $expected ? 'OK' : 'ERRROR').PHP_EOL;
}
test('2020-07-16 16:00:00', '2020-07-16 16:30:00'); // weekday during hours
test('2020-07-16 16:50:00', '2020-07-17 08:20:00'); // weekday during hours until next day
test('2020-07-18 16:50:00', '2020-07-20 08:30:00'); // weekend
test('2020-07-16 06:50:00', '2020-07-16 08:30:00'); // weekday before working hours
test('2020-07-16 20:50:00', '2020-07-17 08:30:00'); // weekday after working hours
test('2020-07-17 16:50:00', '2020-07-20 08:20:00'); // friday during working hours until monday
test('2020-07-17 17:50:00', '2020-07-20 08:30:00'); // friday after hours
```

The output:

```
date: 2020-07-16 16:00:00, expected: 2020-07-16 16:30:00, got: 2020-07-16 16:30:00 OK
date: 2020-07-16 16:50:00, expected: 2020-07-17 08:20:00, got: 2020-07-17 08:20:00 OK
date: 2020-07-18 16:50:00, expected: 2020-07-20 08:30:00, got: 2020-07-20 08:30:00 OK
date: 2020-07-16 06:50:00, expected: 2020-07-16 08:30:00, got: 2020-07-16 08:30:00 OK
date: 2020-07-16 20:50:00, expected: 2020-07-17 08:30:00, got: 2020-07-17 08:30:00 OK
date: 2020-07-17 16:50:00, expected: 2020-07-20 08:20:00, got: 2020-07-20 08:20:00 OK
date: 2020-07-17 17:50:00, expected: 2020-07-20 08:30:00, got: 2020-07-20 08:30:00 OK
```

Tricky part was friday that You didnt really mention, but I added test cases for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot blahy for the response, to calculate the response date, two parameters are passed, one as date and another as expected. Since I have only as reportDate as input with me and expected date should be the output of this calculation, how come I am going to pass expected date as second argument while calling function ? I mean the function should be able to return expected date when called as calculateSLA($reportDate) , or am I missing something here, again thanks for the help :)

Comment: there is only one function you need `function calculateSLA(DateTime $reportDate): DateTime` you pass date of ticket submission and you get the date of max response time (so 30 minutes later). Rest (test function and the invocations below) are just to test if this function is working properly. I'll edit the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks Blahy, my bad I forgot the new construct while calling the function. It is working fine and as expected.